# Invalid Syntax while True statemtn

Tags: python, syntax, while-loop, syntax-error

Here's my script:

```
def makeithappen():
    word=""
    while True:
        try:
            word=inputText()
        except:
            print("Something happened inputText")
        else:
            if len(word)>0:
                break
            elif word!=str:
                break
```

For some reason however I get an invalid syntax error and I am not sure why.

Comment: Your code makes no sense.What exactly  is the output you want?

Comment: Just so you know, stackoverflow does not care about your deadlines.

Comment: Which line? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: The indent of line 2 + 3 does not match.

Comment: @TorbenKlein - OP's post  was edited to make a code block. That error may have happened accidentally there.

Comment: Why there is `else` after `except` block?

Comment: We did a little editing of your script to fit as a code block example on stackoverflow. With these changes I don't get a syntax error.

Comment: @Prajwal - the else is perfectly legal - although I don't know if its wise in this case. From the docs: _The try ... except statement has an optional else clause, which, when present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception_

Comment: @tdelaney OP specifically mentioned that he got a syntax error, and this was the only one to be seen.

Comment: `word=inputText() //is this some defined method or is that supposed to be input()?`

Comment: @TorbenKlein - I didn't see any syntax errors and the code compiles fine for me. What error do you see?

Comment: somebody (maybe you) edited it away ;-)

Comment: always add full error message (Traceback) in question. There are other usefull information - ie. which line makes problem.

Comment: @TorbenKlein - OP posted the code as a paragraph and then somebody else converted it to a code block. That code block had an indentation error, not a syntax error, so I fixed it. I'm hoping OP will comment on the current code. We took it from unreadable to readable now he has to tell us whether we screwed up.

Comment: @tdelaney, you are right, bad indentation gives IndentationError not SyntaxError. My bad.

Comment: OP will get a better grade by not turning it in.

Comment: line 6 shows the problem. it shows a red error before the except. when trying to run the program out of a new file (not the shell) it shows invalid syntax which is why I am mainly confused. inputText is the name of the function I was calling that was defined earlier.

Comment: I believe it maybe something wrong within the formatting but i cannot see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
def makeithappen():
   word=""
   while True: 
       try:
           word=input() #is this supposed to be input()?
       except:
           print("Something happened inputText")
       else: 
           if len(word)>0:
               break
           elif isinstance(word, basestring): #I never got the logic behind it 
               break
```

I think this is what you wanted to do. It exits if entered text is valid (length is more than 0) and input type is not of `str` (which is always `false` in case of python3).

Comment: The canonical way of type checking is isinstance(word, str) or better isinstance(word, basestring).

Comment: Changed it. Thanks, I had totally forgotten `isinstance()`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def makeithappen():
   word=""
   while True:
        try:
           word=raw_input("Go:")
        except:
           print("Something happened inputText")
        else:
           if len(word)>0:
              print("Hello!!")
           elif word!=str:
              print("Bye!!")
              break
makeithappen()
```